# How to get two tf.dataset from tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, labels))

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am working on the Python/tensorflow/mnist tutorial.

Since a few weeks using the orignal code from tensorflow web site i get the warning that the image dataset would soon be deprecated abd that i should use the following one :
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/dataset.py

I load it it my code using :

```
from tensorflow.models.official.mnist import dataset
trainfile = dataset.train(data_dir)
```

Which returns :

```
tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, labels))
```

The issue is that I cannot find a,way to separate them in the following way for example :

```
  trainfile = dataset.train(data_dir)
  train_data= trainfile.images
  train_label= trainfile.label
```

But this clearly doesnot work because the attributrs images and label do not exist. trainfile is a tf.dataset.

Knowing that tf.dataset is made of int32 and float32 i tried :

```
  train_data = trainfile.map(lambda x,y : x.dtype == tf.float32)
```

But it returns and empty dataset.

I insist (but will be open mimded) in doing it this way (two complete batches of image and label) because this is how the tutorial works :

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn

I saw a lot of solution to get elements from datasets but nothing to go back from the zip operations that is done in the following code

```
tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, labels))
```

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can unzip them. One approach is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12851#issuecomment-427432363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784), name='inputs')
outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,), name='outputs')

#Prepare a tensorflow dataset
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))

ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=True).repeat()
iter = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
next = iter.get_next()

inputs = next[0]
outputs = next[1]
```

Comment: Thank you guys. It helped a lot. I read more about iterator and got to understand it in a better way to use both code.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow's `get_single_element()` is finally [around](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#get_single_element) which can be used to unzip features and labels from the dataset.

##### This avoids the need of generating and using an iterator using `.map()`, `iter()` or `one_shot_iterator()` (which could be costly for big datasets).

`get_single_element()` returns a tensor (or a tuple or dict of tensors) encapsulating all the members of the dataset. We need to pass all the members of the dataset batched into a single element.

This can be used to get **features as a tensor-array, or features and labels** as a tuple or dictionary (of tensor-arrays) depending upon how the original dataset was created.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851420/8582902) on SO for an example that unpacks features and labels into a tuple of tensor-arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separating into two datasets, one for images and another for labels, it's best to make a single iterator which returns both the image and the label.

The reason why this is preferred is that it's a lot easier to ensure that you match each example with its label even after a complicated series of shuffles, reorderings, filterings, etc, as you might have in a nontrivial input pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize images and find its associated labels

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))

ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10).batch(batch_size=batch_size)
iter = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
next = iter.get_next()

def display(image, label):
# display image
   ...
   plt.imshow(image)
   ...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    try:
        while True:
             image, label = sess.run(next) 
             # image = numpy array (batch, image_size)
             # label = numpy array (batch, label)
        display(image[0], label[0]) #display first image in batch
    except:
        pass
```