# Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset API, dataset unzip function?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In tensorflow 1.12 there is the `Dataset.zip` function: documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip).

However, I was wondering if there is a dataset unzip function which will return back the original two datasets.

```
# NOTE: The following examples use `{ ... }` to represent the
# contents of a dataset.
a = { 1, 2, 3 }
b = { 4, 5, 6 }
c = { (7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12) }
d = { 13, 14 }

# The nested structure of the `datasets` argument determines the
# structure of elements in the resulting dataset.
Dataset.zip((a, b)) == { (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6) }
Dataset.zip((b, a)) == { (4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3) }

# The `datasets` argument may contain an arbitrary number of
# datasets.
Dataset.zip((a, b, c)) == { (1, 4, (7, 8)),
                            (2, 5, (9, 10)),
                            (3, 6, (11, 12)) }

# The number of elements in the resulting dataset is the same as
# the size of the smallest dataset in `datasets`.
Dataset.zip((a, d)) == { (1, 13), (2, 14) }
```

I would like to have the following

```
dataset = Dataset.zip((a, d)) == { (1, 13), (2, 14) }
a, d = dataset.unzip()
```

Comment: Still an open issue for this on github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12851

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My workaround was to just use map, not sure if there might be interest in a syntax sugar function for `unzip` later though.

```
a = dataset.map(lambda a, b: a)
b = dataset.map(lambda a, b: b)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no guarantee a and b will be in the same order (share the same index).

Comment: @random_dsp_guy what do yoou mean? unless you shuffle one of the datasets or use `deterministic=False` in map calls they will have the same order.

Comment: I can confirm that if you shuffle the zipped dataset, a and b will not be aligned as before.
Very dangerous operation.

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow's `get_single_element()` is finally [around](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#get_single_element) which can be used to unzip datasets (as asked in the question above).

##### This avoids the need of generating and using an iterator using `.map()` or `iter()` (which could be costly for big datasets).

`get_single_element()` returns a tensor (or a tuple or dict of tensors) encapsulating all the members of the dataset. We need to pass all the members of the dataset batched into a single element.

This can be used to get **features as a tensor-array, or features and labels** as a tuple or dictionary (of tensor-arrays) depending upon how the original dataset was created.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
b = [ 4, 5, 6 ]
c = [ (7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12) ]
d = [ 13, 14 ]
# Creating datasets from lists
ads = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
bds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(b)
cds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(c)
dds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(d)

list(tf.data.Dataset.zip((ads, bds)).as_numpy_iterator()) == [ (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6) ] # True
list(tf.data.Dataset.zip((bds, ads)).as_numpy_iterator()) == [ (4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3) ] # True

# Let's zip and unzip ads and dds
x = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ads, dds))
xa, xd = tf.data.Dataset.get_single_element(x.batch(len(x)))
xa = list(xa.numpy())
xd = list(xd.numpy())
print(xa, xd) # [1,2] [13, 14] # notice how xa is now different from a because ads was curtailed when zip was done above.
d == xd # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Ouwen Huang's answer, this function seems to work for arbitrary datasets:

```
def split_datasets(dataset):
    tensors = {}
    names = list(dataset.element_spec.keys())
    for name in names:
        tensors[name] = dataset.map(lambda x: x[name])

    return tensors
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a more general unzip function for [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) pipelines, which also handles the **recursive case** where a pipeline has multiple levels of zipping.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def tfdata_unzip(
    tfdata: tf.data.Dataset,
    *,
    recursive: bool=False,
    eager_numpy: bool=False,
    num_parallel_calls: int=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
):
    """
    Unzip a zipped tf.data pipeline.

    Args:
        tfdata: the :py:class:`tf.data.Dataset`
            to unzip.

        recursive: Set to ``True`` to recursively unzip
            multiple layers of zipped pipelines.
            Defaults to ``False``.

        eager_numpy: Set this to ``True`` to return
            Python lists of primitive types or
            :py:class:`numpy.array` objects. Defaults
            to ``False``.

        num_parallel_calls: The level of parallelism to
            each time we ``map()`` over a
            :py:class:`tf.data.Dataset`.

    Returns:
        Returns a Python list of either
             :py:class:`tf.data.Dataset` or NumPy
             arrays.
    """
    if isinstance(tfdata.element_spec, tf.TensorSpec):
        if eager_numpy:
            return list(tfdata.as_numpy_iterator())
        return tfdata
        
    
    def tfdata_map(i: int) -> list:
        return tfdata.map(
            lambda *cols: cols[i],
            deterministic=True,
            num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls,
        )

    if isinstance(tfdata.element_spec, tuple):
        num_columns = len(tfdata.element_spec)
        if recursive:
            return [
                tfdata_unzip(
                    tfdata_map(i),
                    recursive=recursive,
                    eager_numpy=eager_numpy,
                    num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls,
                )
                for i in range(num_columns)
            ]
        else:
            return [
                tfdata_map(i)
                for i in range(num_columns)
            ]

    raise ValueError(
        "Unknown tf.data.Dataset element_spec: " +
        str(tfdata.element_spec)
    )
```

Here is how `tfdata_unzip()` works, given these example datasets:

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> baby = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
    np.array([1,2]),
    np.array([3,4]),
    np.array([5,6]),
])
>>> baby.element_spec
TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)
TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)

>>> parent = tf.data.Dataset.zip((baby, baby))
>>> parent.element_spec
(TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))

>>> grandparent = tf.data.Dataset.zip((parent, parent))
>>> grandparent.element_spec
((TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None),
  TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)),
 (TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None),
  TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)))
```

This is what `tfdata_unzip()` returns on the above `baby`, `parent`, and `grandparent` datasets:

```py
>>> tfdata_unzip(baby)
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int64>

>>> tfdata_unzip(parent)
[<ParallelMapDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int64>,
 <ParallelMapDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int64>]

>>> tfdata_unzip(grandparent)
[<ParallelMapDataset shapes: ((2,), (2,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>,
 <ParallelMapDataset shapes: ((2,), (2,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>]

>>> tfdata_unzip(grandparent, recursive=True)
[[<ParallelMapDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int64>,
  <ParallelMapDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int64>],
 [<ParallelMapDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int64>,
  <ParallelMapDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.int64>]]

>>> tfdata_unzip(grandparent, recursive=True, eager_numpy=True)
[[[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])],
  [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]],
 [[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])],
  [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]]]
```