# Extract target from Tensorflow PrefetchDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, prefetch

I am still learning tensorflow and keras, and I suspect this question has a very easy answer I'm just missing due to lack of familiarity.

I have a `PrefetchDataset` object:

```
> print(tf_test)
$ <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 99), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
```

...made up of features and a target. I can iterate over it using a `for` loop:

```
> for example in tf_test:
>     print(example[0].numpy())
>     print(example[1].numpy())
>     exit()
$ [[-0.31 -0.94 -1.12 ... 0.18 -0.27]
   [-0.22 -0.54 -0.14 ... 0.33 -0.55]
   [-0.60 -0.02 -1.41 ... 0.21 -0.63]
   ...
   [-0.03 -0.91 -0.12 ... 0.77 -0.23]
   [-0.76 -1.48 -0.15 ... 0.38 -0.35]
   [-0.55 -0.08 -0.69 ... 0.44 -0.36]]
  [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
   ...
   0 1 1 0]
```

However, this is very slow.  What I'd like to do is access the tensor corresponding to the class labels and turn that into a numpy array, or a list, or any sort of iterable that can be fed into scikit-learn's classification report and/or confusion matrix:

```
> y_pred = model.predict(tf_test)
> print(y_pred)
$ [[0.01]
   [0.14]
   [0.00]
   ...
   [0.32]
   [0.03]
   [0.00]]
> y_pred_list = [int(x[0]) for x in y_pred]             # assumes value >= 0.5 is positive prediction
> y_true = []                                           # what I need help with
> print(sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred_list)
```

...OR access the data such that it could be used in tensorflow's confusion matrix:

```
> labels = []                                           # what I need help with
> predictions = y_pred_list                             # could we just use a tensor?
> print(tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions)
```

In both cases, the general ability to grab the target data from the original object in a manner that isn't computationally expensive would be very helpful (and might help with my underlying intuitions re: tensorflow and keras).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823218/5238639 This has the answer
`y = np.concatenate([y for x, y in ds], axis=0)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert it to a list with `list(ds)` and then recompile it as a normal Dataset with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(ds))`. From there your nightmare begins again but at least it's a nightmare that other people have had before.

Note that for more complex datasets (e.g. nested dictionaries) you will need more preprocessing after calling `list(ds)`, but this should work for the example you asked about.

This is far from a satisfying answer but unfortunately the class is entirely undocumented and none of the standard Dataset tricks work.

Comment: I know the class is entirely undocumented but this answer is Good :)

Comment: @DevLoverUmar glad it helped :)

Answer (score 8):

You can turn use `map` to select either the input or label from every `(input, label)` pair, and turn this into a list:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inputs = np.random.rand(100, 99)
targets = np.random.rand(100)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs, targets))

X_train = list(map(lambda x: x[0], ds))
y_train = list(map(lambda x: x[1], ds))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to retain the batches or extract all the labels as a single tensor you could use the following function:

```py
def get_labels_from_tfdataset(tfdataset, batched=False):

    labels = list(map(lambda x: x[1], tfdataset)) # Get labels 

    if not batched:
        return tf.concat(labels, axis=0) # concat the list of batched labels

    return labels
```

Answer (score 4):

You can generate lists by looping your **PrefetchDataset** which is train_dataset in my example;

```
train_data = [(example.numpy(), label.numpy()) for example, label in train_dataset]
```

Thus you can reach every single example and label separately by using indexes;

```
train_data[0][0]
train_data[0][1]
```

You can also convert them into data frame with 2 columns by using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=['example', 'label'])
```

Then, if you want to convert back your list into PrefetchFataset, you can simply use ;

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
lambda: train_data, ( tf.string, tf.int32)) # you should define dtypes of yours
```

And you can check if it worked with this ;

```
list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
```

Comment: This is simple but work very well in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This is the class returned by the Dataset.prefetch() method, and it is a subclass of Dataset.

If you set skip_prefetch=Ture by passing a ReadConfig to the builder, the returned type will be _OptionsDataset instead.

```
read_config = tfds.ReadConfig(skip_prefetch = True)
dataset_builder.as_dataset(
    ......,
    read_config = read_config,
)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with my object like this:

```
type(train_ds)
>> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset
```

I managed to extract the features and the labels from a batch that way:

```
[(train_features, label_batch)] = train_ds.take(1)
print(np.array(label_batch))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created your `tf.data.Dataset` using batches and you want two separate numpy arrays this will take each list of lists and concatenate them into a single array.

```
train_data = list(train_ds)
features = np.concatenate([train_data[n][0] for n in range(0, len(train_data))])
targets = np.concatenate([train_data[n][1] for n in range(0, len(train_data))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use map() function to iterate over at once 
`ratings.map(lambda x: x["feature name"])`

Answer (score 0):

## For image dataset, Tensorflow 2.12.0

## Load data

```
 dataset, dataset_info = tfds.load('malaria', with_info=True, as_supervised=True,shuffle_files=True,split["train"],data_dir="you_dir\tensorflow_datasets\\")
```

## Iterate through samples

```
  for i, (image, label) in enumerate(train_dataset.take(16)):
        ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.title(dataset_info.features['label'].int2str(label))
        plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```