# Accessing Images and Labels Inside a tf.data.Dataset Object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.data.dataset

I'm following along the [keras tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/) on image classification. I have created a `tf.data.Dataset` and specified a single batch using the `.take()` method:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "data",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    image_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32)

train_batch = train_ds.take(1)
```

Inspecting the `train_batch` object, as expected, I see it is made up of two objects: images and labels:

```
<TakeDataset shapes: ((None, 224, 224, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

The tutorial states uses the following code to plot the images in this batch:

```
for images, labels in train_batch:
    for i in range(32):
        ax = plt.subplot(4, 8, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
```

My question is how does `for images, labels in train_batch:` manage to specify the images and labels separately. Apart from `enumerate`  I have not come across specifying two variables in a for loop. Is this the only way to access the images and labels in a batch?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226621/how-to-extract-data-labels-back-from-tensorflow-dataset

Answer (score 0):

train_batch returns a tuple (image,label). take for example the code below

```
x=(1,2,3)
a,b,c=x
print ('a= ', a,' b= ',b,' c= ', c)
# the result will be a=  1  b=  2  c=  3
```

same process happens in the for loop images receives the image part of the tuple and labels receives the label part of the tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however if I defined x=(1,2,3) and then tried the iterator as was described in the keras example above, I would get: for a,b,c in x: which raises an exception. Is it because a tf.data.dataset is similar to a zip object?