# How to load images and labels seperately in a dataset loaded by tensorflow_datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_ds = tfds.load('cifar100', split='train[:90%]').shuffle(1024).batch(32)
val_ds = tfds.load('cifar100', split='train[-10%:]').shuffle(1024).batch(32)
```

I want to convert `train_ds` and `val_ds` into something like this: `x_train, y_train` and `x_val, y_val` (x for images and y for labels).
The Keras API uses train and test data split (this seems to be the case in sklearn too), but I do **not** want to use any test data at all here.

I have tried this, but it didn't work (and I do understand why this doesn't work, but I don't know how else can I convert my training data to images and labels):

```py
x_train = train_ds['image']

# TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: [Does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226621/how-to-extract-data-labels-back-from-tensorflow-dataset) answer your question?

Comment: I tried all the proposed solutions, but I keep running into this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: and I think what is being asked in that question is different from my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution:

```py
train_ds, val_ds = tfds.load(name="cifar100", split=('train[:90%]','train[-10%:]'), batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True)

x_train, y_train = tfds.as_numpy(train_data)
x_val, y_val = tfds.as_numpy(val_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way, I created lists firstly to inspect them. I think you want something like:

```
train_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train[:90%]')

train_examples_labels = tfds.as_numpy(train_ds)

x_train = []
y_train = []


for features_labels in train_examples_labels:
    x_train.append(features_labels['image'])
    y_train.append(features_labels['label'])
```

`features_labels` is a dictionary here:

```
features_labels.keys()
dict_keys(['image', 'label'])
```

After you can convert them into `numpy` arrays.

```
x_train = np.array(x_train, dtype = 'float32')
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype = 'float32')
```

Comment: I used your method but then when compared to the train data loaded by Keras API:

```(x_train_keras, y_train_keras), (x_test_keras, y_test_keras) = cifar100.load_data()
y_train_keras == y_train

array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ...,
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]])```

Comment: They might not be in the same order. I checked the shapes, they were same.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I haven't shuffled my data so I was wondering why the order is different

Comment: also, for some reason I'm unable to convert the final arrays to float32

Comment: I checked the class distributions, they are equal just not ordered exactly. I am able to convert them as `float32`, check the edited answer.

Comment: I found out that this was caused by batching the data during import. thanks for the help!