# 'Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float' on imshow()

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to show images from my dataset. But on imshow() function I have this error.
'Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float'

This is my code:

```
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  '/media/Tesi/',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(360, 360),
  batch_size=18)


probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, 
                                         tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])

predictions = probability_model.predict(val_ds)
predictions[0]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

for i in range(25):
  plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.imshow(val_ds, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
  plt.xlabel(class_names[predictions[i]])
plt.show()
```

Can I solve it?
Thank you,
Best regards

Comment: `val_ds` is a `tf.data.Dataset` object, so you need to extract the images from that object: [How to extract data/labels back from TensorFlow dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56226621/13138364)

Comment: Yes, I think that this is the problem. But the function np.concatenate returns me `iteration over a 0-d array`. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

`image_dataset_from_directory` function uses `cv2.imread()` as function to read images from your directory. Though, `cv2.imread()` returns `None` if file weren't found. None is type `object`. So, check your path

Comment: My images are in '/media/Tesi/conducente' and in '/media/Tesi/passeggero'.
The folder Tesi has two folders.

Comment: So, I think It's correct. I have used this path until now and it work.

Comment: You should convert your annotations to pandas dataframe and add filepaths there. Then use flow_from_dataframe() function. Or you always may load data manually

Comment: I've already tried this. Anyway, I'm not able tho show images of val_ds and its predictions.

Comment: You mean that you have tried to load images manually and it didn't work?

Comment: Both. Manually and with pandas