# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes when looking at mask

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I seem to be having some issues with creating a TensorFlow iterator object to feed in to a deep learning model. I am still very new to TensorFlow in general, but had a working example that I now can't seem to replicate.

The code itself seems to fail when attempting to iterate through my created tensorflow dataset using either `iter(train_dataset)` OR `for i in train_dataset: print i`. The shape and component that the error refers to is my mask layer. As you can see in the code below, I squeeze the np.array to remove the last dimension prior to one-hot encoding, then use `tf.one_hot` to transform the categorical data. Printing the shape before and after this confirms that I have replaced the 1 dimension multi-value mask with a dimension containing 9 separate arrays.

I am attempting to train a semantic segmentation model using a multispectral (12-channel) image and a mask layer containing 9 values (labeled 0 -8).

I have looked at as many shape-related tensorflow tickets such as [here](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-1-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected-shape-none-6-216-1-found-shape-none-216-1/14905) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383268/i-am-getting-error-like-input-1-of-layer-model-5-is-incompatible-with-the-lay). The closest thing I can find to my issue is [here](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/incompatible-shapes/7209), however this refers to a different stage when they're actually applying the model - at this point I'm not that far through my script, i'm simply trying to read the pipeline I've just created!

Code is:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import segmentation_models as sm
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import MeanIoU
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import load_model
import tifffile
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import glob
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_raster, reshape_as_image
import argparse
import time
import shutil

# create argument parser for easier training
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Prepare mask and image for tensorflow deep learning training."
)

parser.add_argument(
      "-t", "--tensorDir", help="Path of the tensorflow directory where prepare_imagery.py placed image/ mask patches.",
      required=True, dest="tensorDir", metavar="DIRECTORY"
)

parser.add_argument(
      "-n", "--modelName", help="Name of dl model to create (.hdf5 extension required)",
      required=True, dest="modelName", metavar="'STRING.HDF5'"
)

args = parser.parse_args()

# assign and sort variables
root_directory = os.path.abspath(args.tensorDir)
os.chdir(root_directory)

model_name = args.modelName


train_img_dir = "./train_images/train/"
train_mask_dir = "./train_masks/train/"

val_img_dir = "./val_images/val/"
val_mask_dir = "./val_masks/val/"

train_images = glob.glob(train_img_dir + '*.tif')
train_masks = glob.glob(train_mask_dir + '*.tif')

val_images = glob.glob(val_img_dir + '*.tif')
val_masks = glob.glob(val_mask_dir + '*.tif')


train_images.sort()
train_masks.sort()
val_images.sort()
val_masks.sort()

num_images = len(os.listdir(train_img_dir))
print(f'Total number of images used to train model is: {num_images}')
print(f'Data type of image is: {rasterio.open(train_images[0]).dtypes}')
print(f'Data type of mask is: {rasterio.open(train_masks[0]).dtypes}')

seed=24
batch_size= 16
n_classes= 9
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'

def read_image(path):
    x = rasterio.open(path).read()
    x = reshape_as_image(x)
    # x = x / 255.0 #normalise
    # x = x.astype(np.float32) #convert to float
    return x

def read_mask(path):
    x = rasterio.open(path).read()
    x = reshape_as_image(x)
    # x = x / 255.0 # normalise
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1) # add channel size to shape of np array
    # x = x.astype(np.float32) #convert to float
    return x

preprocess_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)

def mask_to_categorical(image, mask, n_class):
    mask = tf.squeeze(mask, axis=-1)
    #print(mask.shape)
    mask = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(mask, tf.uint8), n_class)
    #print(mask.shape)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
    return image, mask

def preprocess(x, y):
    def f(x, y):
        x = x.decode()
        y = y.decode()

        x = read_image(x)
        y = read_mask(y)

        return x, y
    images, masks = tf.numpy_function(f, [x, y], [tf.uint16, tf.uint8])
    images.set_shape([256,256,12])
    masks.set_shape([256,256,1])

    images, masks = mask_to_categorical(images, masks, n_classes)
    return images, masks

def tf_dataset(x, y, batch):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    return dataset

train_dataset = tf_dataset(train_images, train_masks, batch_size)
val_dataset = tf_dataset(val_images, val_masks, batch_size)

print(f'DATASET IS: {train_dataset}')

train_img_gen = iter(train_dataset)
val_img_gen = iter(val_dataset)


print(val_img_gen.element_spec)

x, y = train_img_gen.get_next()
```

Traceback message is:

```
2023-06-01 12:39:35.367510: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:110] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-06-01 12:39:35.416638: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-06-01 12:39:35.973884: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Segmentation Models: using `keras` framework.
Total number of images used to train model is: 156
Data type of image is: ('uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16', 'uint16')
Data type of mask is: ('uint8',)
2023-06-01 12:39:38.371259: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.417293: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.417509: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.419055: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.419228: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.419356: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.924564: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.924756: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.924899: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-06-01 12:39:38.925012: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4069 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
DATASET IS: <_RepeatDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 12), dtype=tf.uint16, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 9), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
2023-06-01 12:39:39.095075: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_1' with dtype string and shape [156]
     [[{{node Placeholder/_1}}]]
2023-06-01 12:39:39.095393: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_1' with dtype string and shape [156]
     [[{{node Placeholder/_1}}]]
2023-06-01 12:39:39.130062: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_0' with dtype string and shape [52]
     [[{{node Placeholder/_0}}]]
2023-06-01 12:39:39.130386: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_1' with dtype string and shape [52]
     [[{{node Placeholder/_1}}]]
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 12), dtype=tf.uint16, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 9), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bwright/Documents/passive/lulc/scripts/train_model.py", line 155, in <module>
    x, y = train_img_gen.get_next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bwright/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 850, in get_next
    return self._next_internal()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bwright/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 780, in _next_internal
    ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bwright/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 3016, in iterator_get_next
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/home/bwright/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7262, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Incompatible shapes at component 1: expected [?,256,256,9] but got [16,256,256,1,9]. [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

I realise there also seems to be a problem with the GPU, but one problem at a time!