# How to unpack the data from tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

## This is my code about loading data from tfrecord:

```
def read_tfrecord(tfrecord, epochs, batch_size):

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord)

    def parse(record):
        features = {
            "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            "target": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
        example = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, features)
        image = decode_image(example["image"])
        label = tf.cast(example["target"], tf.int32)
        return image, label

    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)        
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)  #
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs)

    return dataset


x_train, y_train = read_tfrecord(tfrecord=train_files, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

## I got the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

## My question is:

How to unpack the data from dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
dataset = read_tfrecord(tfrecord=train_files, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

iterator = iter(dataset)

x, y = next(iterator)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset = read_tfrecord(tfrecord=train_files, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
# the above should return an iterator
for x, y in dataset:
    print(x)
    print(y)
    # now the unpacking parsing happens
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow's `get_single_element()` is finally [around](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#get_single_element) which can be used to unpack datasets.

##### This avoids the need of generating and using an iterator using `.map()` or `iter()` (which could be costly for big datasets).

`get_single_element()` returns a tensor (or a tuple or dict of tensors) encapsulating all the members of the dataset. We need to pass all the members of the dataset batched into a single element.

This can be used to get **features as a tensor-array, or features and labels** as a tuple or dictionary (of tensor-arrays) depending upon how the original dataset was created.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851420/8582902) on SO for an example that unpacks features and labels into a tuple of tensor-arrays.