# Multiple inputs(list of dataset) for tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I want to use list of dataset as a input for .fit() function but it returns:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

I find same question [Input multiple datasets to tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979750/input-multiple-datasets-to-tensorflow-model) but the data I use is more than 100gb and it does not fit to RAM.

So I can not convert the prefetch data to normal tf tensor. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) it only supports single `tf.data` instance.

Instead of providing multiple `tf.data.Dataset` instance you can combine them before using `concatenate` like below.

```
a = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)  # ==> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
b = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 8)  # ==> [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
ds = a.concatenate(b)
```